# Zurb foundation 6 sticky menu in a project that have been created with generator-gulp-angular

Tags: angularjs, gulp, zurb-foundation, sticky

I have been set up two projects, the first one manually  and the other one using [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) tools(with  “jQuery 2.x” and “The official jQuery implementation of Foundation” options). In both , foundation.css and foundation.js have been injected in index.html.

index.html (first project):

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
</head>
<body >
….
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).foundation();
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html (second project):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
 ...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css"> //foundation.css has been injected in index.css
</head>
<body>
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js">  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is part of a HTML file that in both project is the same:

```
<div id="stickhere" />
<div data-sticky-container>
   <nav class="sticky" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;anchor:stickhere;"   >
     <ul class="menu" data-magellan >
      <li><a href="#foo1">#foo1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foo2">#foo2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foo3">#foo3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foo4">#foo4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foo5">#foo5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foo6">#foo6</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
```

As you can see I want to have a sticky menu that stick to 'stickhere' element.

In the first project , sticky menu works as  expected. But in the second project, the menu scroll up/down with page scrolling up/down.

Using Inspect context menu in Google Chrome, I have copied   'data-sticky-container' element from both projects at  run time and result is:

The first project

```
<div data-sticky-container="" class="sticky-container" style="height: 40px;">
<nav class="sticky is-at-top is-stuck" data-sticky="69v1vb-sticky" data-options="marginTop:0;anchor:stickhere;" data-resize="orhhfj-sticky" data-events="resize" style="max-width: 1200px; margin-top: 0em; top: 0px; bottom: auto; left: 32.5px;">
  <ul class="menu" data-magellan="tysnpu-magellan" data-resize="q54qzr-magellan" data-scroll="q54qzr-magellan" id="q54qzr-magellan" data-events="resize">
    <li><a href="#foo1" class="">#foo1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#foo2" class="active">#foo2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#foo3" class="">#foo3</a></li>
  </ul>  
</nav>
```

The second project

```
<div data-sticky-container="" class="sticky-container" style="height: 40px;">
<nav class="sticky" data-sticky="9defbv-sticky" data-options="marginTop:0;anchor:stickhere;" data-resize="yvriij-sticky" style="max-width: 1200px;" data-events="resize">
  <ul class="menu" data-magellan="07xwd5-magellan" data-resize="c7qbpd-magellan" data-scroll="c7qbpd-magellan" id="c7qbpd-magellan" data-events="resize">
    <li><a href="#foo1" class="active">#foo1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#foo2" class="">#foo2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#foo3" class="">#foo3</a></li>
  </ul>  
</nav>
```

In the second one 'is-at-top is-stuck' attributes not injected in class part of Nav element and also style parts are different.

How can I have a working sticky menu in the second project?

**Foundation version : 6.2.3  (also tested 6.2.1)**

**jquery version: 2.2.4**

**generator-gulp-angular: 1.7**

**>EDIT 1:**
Also browser log shows this warning:

> Tried to initialize sticky on an element that already has a Foundation
>   plugin.

Comment: try using position:fixed;

Comment: Adding "position:fixed;" did not change the result.

Comment: Is this code exist `$(document).foundation();` in the second project?

Comment: Yes, In 'run' phase of second project: $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
         $(document).foundation();
     });

Answer (score 0):

I‌‌ don't know what is difference between two projects. But ,changing nav element in the second project, to

```
 <nav class="sticky" data-sticky data-top-anchor="stickhere:top">
```

solved the problem.